# Redirect to another controller/action in anther application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have to build an ASP.NET MVC 3 application that can redirect to other ASP.NET MVC 3 applications by calling their controller/action. I was thinking of just building the URL. I would have to know the controller/action names and the host. I was thinking of storing the Host strings in a database so if the app is moved I would be able to update the database with this information without making changes to code and recompiling. I'm just not sure if this is the best approach. Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you absolutely have to know the controllers and action names unless you share a common routing table. However if you think if the destination application as a service, then this is fine as you have restful urls to the service endpoints, as would be typical in any app that calls a service. I would however store these in a single location - as you mentioned table, config file, etc.

Comment: Thanks Adam for your response. After looking at how they set up their IIS virtual directory I see that the app I'm working on is the parent and all the other apps are sub apps. Any controller in main app will know what sub app/controller/action to call so I was thinking all I have to do is call Redirect("appName/ControllerName/ActionName") and append any querystrings to this. Does that sound right??

Comment: ya. If its always a subdirectory you can get the current apps url using a "~" at the beginning and add on the folders underneath. Several ways to do it here but essentially, ya you have it correct. Im assuming those uris are all stored somewhere though for easy future changes : )

Comment: I was thinking about that but since each controller will know what app to call I didn't know if it was over kill putting in web.config or database.

Answer (score 1):

In general, 3rd party integration is always easier and more maintainable when it's done in a black box manner. Rather than integrate based on how a 3rd party implements their solutions, you integrate based on their black box facade, so that you don't have to deal with knowing their implementation details.

Comparing it to a SQL query - a SQL query typically describes just what you want, rather than how you want the database server to retrieve what you want.